# When setting UIToolBar as inputAccessoryView to UITextField hides the UIToolBar

Tags: ios, ios4, uitextfield, uitoolbar

I have tried one sample from the [this link](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/examples/iphone-PickerObjectOnButton.html)

Actually what i tried is placed an uitextfield and added that toolbar as inputaccessoryview.

When i tap on the uitexfield, it shows the uikeyboard with that toolbar added on top that is ok.
But the toolbar which was showing under the pickervieew is now get hidden after i did the above thing...

Please let me know why is that happening

Answer (score 0):

If you mean your app had a toolbar at the bottom, and the picker view/keyboard/other input view appears on top of this, then this is the expected behaviour.

For example, look at mobile safari, when you enter text in a field on the page (like an SO answer, for example!), the keyboard covers the lower toolbar. Otherwise you'd hit it when typing.

Comment: what i am saying is i can use the toolbar on top of the uipickerview that is fine. but when i set the same toolbar into uitextfield inputaccessoryview, the toolbar is not showing on the uipickerview.this is my problem..pls let me know your advice